# Windows Update Error 800B0100

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-update

I am having that error code while downloading Windows Update files.

Anyone have similar experience with this? I searched around and found all of them related to Windows Vista, not Windows Server.

Here's the screenshot from the server:
[WinUpdateError](http://img229.yfrog.com/img229/4496/winupdateerror.png)

**Update** (01/08/2009):

I have decided to revisit the problem rerun CheckSUR, and found out the problem came from "CBS MUM Missing" from Windows Update client Self Update.

```
(f) CBS MUM Missing 0x00000002  servicing\packages\WUClient-SelfUpdate-Core-CoreComp~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~7.2.6001.788.mum       
(f) CBS MUM Missing 0x00000002  servicing\packages\WUClient-SelfUpdate-Core-TopLevel~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~7.2.6001.788.mum       
(f) CBS MUM Missing 0x00000002  servicing\packages\WUClient-SelfUpdate-Core~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~7.2.6001.788.mum
```

I can't find any KB related to this, any help?

Answer (score 2):

From Wikipedia: Windows Server 2008 is built from the same code base as Windows Vista; therefore, it shares much of the same architecture and functionality.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/956702 mentions a potential fix for Server 2008.

Comment: I tried KB947821 (which comes from KB956702), no effect.
And I did look on Google, you don't have to give me that link; if you examined the result, there really no solution that are relevant to Windows Server 2008, even though some pages are returned.

Comment: 956702 specifically mentions Server 2008.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that with Server 2008 if I get a Windows update error a reboot usually fixes it. Irritatingly restarting the automatic updates service makes no difference; it has to be a reboot.

JR